# close pop up window and redirect to parent window in struts2

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I have pop up window , in which to upload an excel file of adding new users.
After clicking the button and successfully added the users into DB, I want to close the pop up window and refresh the parent window to see the updates. In Parent Window, it shows the list of users.

***How can I handle all of these events and steps in Struts2 and javascript?***

```
function callAddUsers() {
            document.frmUpload.action = "addUsers.action";
            document.frmUpload.submit();
            }
```

I want to display some messages of how many users added in parent window too. How can I pass all those info by action?

*Now the problem is when I successfully uploaded and added users, the popup window displays the list of users and I have two window opened.*

Thanks.

Comment: so simple the solution is.. :) just `window.close();` the popup window and `target="main"` , in here just target the iframe name of the parent window. all works perfectly :) no more headache.. :)

Comment: you didnt mentioned any iframe in the question. Are you using a pop-up window or an iframe?

Comment: @anu, I made pop up window from javascript. and close that pop up window by using `window.close();` and then, just target the main window ( iframe or frame, it doesn't matter). for my case, it is just a simple window.

Comment: but the menu page(included) I use is a simple iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution.

just `window.close();` the popup window and `target="main"` , in here just target name of the parent window. all works perfectly :)